# Accessing raster values to create histogram using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, histogram, raster-dataset

Using native Python and arcpy function what method is best to create a histogram of raster dataset? I know it's possible to use raterio and GDAL functions, but I would like to keep it a arcpy and native Python.

Specifically I am working on a script to delineate watersheds and I would like to create a raster based on the values in a flow accumulation raster dataset. From the calculated raster I would then convert to vector stream layers. The ultimate goal is to be able to create separate stream order layers.

Comment: "Is it possible?" questions are of limited use here, since the answer is nearly always an unhelpful, "Yes." Please [Edit] the question to focus on the "How is it possible?" using your own Python code as a starting point (all coding questions are expected to contain code).

Comment: @Vince thank you. I have edited my question. At this time I do not have a code sample to provide because at this time I do not know where to start on this problem within my script.

Comment: What's wrong with standard stream order tool in  hydrology toolbox?

Comment: @FelixIP I would like to use that tool, but it requires a stream raster. I would like to use the histogram of the flow accumulation values to determine the threshold values for the stream raster layer. If there is a better way to do this, I am all ears. This was just the way I thought I might be able to determine them.

Comment: Should be hydrological things to account for. 3ha is common for urban subcatchments. Histogram will look weird anyway, when you think of what it represents.

Comment: With natural streams, I'd query flow accumulation at their starts at the places with different soils and perhaps use variable thresholds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend converting your [raster to a numpy array](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/rastertonumpyarray-function.htm), which you can then use to calculate statistics for the histogram. [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) is then used for the plotting. For example:

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# This example uses an 8bit unsigned format TIFF image
tiff = r'C:\path\to\your\image.tif'

# Convert raster to numpy array and calculate histogram
array = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(tiff)
hist, bins = np.histogram(array, bins = [25,50,75,100,125,150,175,200,225,250,275])

# Plot the histogram
plt.bar(bins[:-1], hist, width = 25)
plt.xlim(min(bins), max(bins))
plt.ylabel('Pixel Count')
plt.xlabel('Pixel Values')
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

However, I believe [Rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/plotting.html?highlight=plot#plotting) does a better job plotting raster histograms. For example, here is a Rasterio generated histogram of 4 band NAIP imagery:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show_hist

src = rasterio.open("path/to/your/image.tif")
show_hist(
    src, bins=50, lw=0.0, stacked=False, alpha=0.3,
    histtype='stepfilled', title="Histogram")
```

[image]

Comment: Is this tool able to be run on a raster dataset or will I need to export the raster from my gdb to run it?

Comment: @EthanGoss You should be able to use a FGDB raster.

Comment: @Aaron: +1. Is there a way to automatically choose the bin values based on the min  & max values in the raster file? Thanks

Comment: @Tung Yes, you can certainly modify the bins based on min max values. However, I would recommend opening a new question for that.